# Does GAE support the new GCM (released at I/O 15) yet?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

A new version of GCM was released at I/O 15 which uses a GCM reg token instead of an ID and has new features.

The GAE library for server-side GCM is "com.ganyo:gcm-server:1.0.2" (gradle form of Maven reference).  I figure that the answer to my question is 'no' because searching for a new version on Maven I don't see anything:
http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cgcm-server

Am I looking in the right places?  Or will it come in a new GAE SDK?

I figure I could bypass the GAE library and formulate my own calls to the GCM servers, but why bother - makes more sense to wait (and to ask)?

Or perhaps I can keep using the old library and just substitute the new token for the old ID (as long as I don't need the new functionality)?

Comment: Did you find an answer? I want to know this too.

Comment: @dustedrob no, no answer yet